# htaccess not working with WAMP 2.5 Virtual Host outside of wamp/www directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My `httpd.conf`:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

My `hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       firstdrive
::1             firstdrive
```

I have tried lots of configurations for `httpd-vhosts.conf` but this is what it looks like at the moment:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride all
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/sites/mysite/public_html"
    ServerName mysite
    <Directory  "c:/sites/mysite">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>    
    <Directory  "c:/sites/mysite/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What works:

- Home page loads, CSS works.

What doesn't work:

- The links in my menu are like this: `href="/index/"`. This is because in my `.htaccess` file I redirect all requests for `page.php` to `page/`, simply because I think it looks better in the browser. So when I click on a link on the page, I get a 404 error. Inspecting Chrome's Developer Tools I see that my redirect in my `.htaccess` is not working. To confirm this, I put "this should break it" into my `.htaccess` file to see if I would get a 500 error, but my home page still loads.

A few notes:

- Yes I restarted WAMP whenever I changed `httpd.conf` or `httpd-vhosts.conf`.
- `.htaccess` works fine if I create the Virtual Host here: `wamp/www/mysite`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.